# react-dropdown-tree-select: Close dropdown on select

Tags: reactjs, react-dropdown-tree-select

Is it possible to access any prop to minimize the dropdown after a node is selected. My use-case is to select only nodes in the deepest level and leaving parent nodes disabled. On selection of a single node, the expected behaviour would be to minimise the dropdown, instead of clicking outside. Can this be achieved with JavaScript without leveraging CSS?